# fopen() doesn't work, despite the file clearly existing

Tags: c, linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, fopen, wsl-2

When running my C code on WSL (ubuntu), I'm attempting to use fopen() on a file that 100%, positively, absolutely exists. And yet, it keeps saying that it doesn't exist despite it 100%, positively, absolutely existing.

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

char *path = "/bin/";
char *line;

// runs batch mode (tests use this mode)
if (argc == 2) {
    char *line;
    FILE *fp;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(argv[1]); i++) {
        if (argv[1][i] == '\n') {
            argv[1][i] == '\0';
        }
    }

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fp == NULL) {
        perror("fopen");
    }
```

I'm 100% certain that it's searching in the correct directory, because if I change the mode from "r" to "w", it creates a file with an identical name in the correct directory, right next to the file that already exists with the same name.

I'm seriously at the end of my rope. Absolutely none of this makes sense, especially how it doesn't pick up on there being duplicate files. Can someone please help?

Comment: Get a list of files in that directory using `opendir`, then compare the names byte by byte.

Comment: How do you enter the file name? Do you type by hand or use tab-completion to let the shell pick the existing file?

Comment: The program is being called from a script that my professor wrote.

Comment: Then you should try to call it manually using tab completion. I guess there are strange/non-printable characters in either the name of the existing file or in the name passed to the program.

Comment: Post the exact error message please

Comment: Verify by using the path as constant instead of trying to use it from arguments, i.e. minimise unknowns...

Comment: "identical name in the correct directory, right next to the file that already exists with the same name.." --> 2 files with the same name???  Sounds like one has characters that you do not "see".  Likely the argument that code passes in is **not* the same as the one you edit in.

Comment: `argv[1][i] == '\0';` is technically allowed, but risky in that this feature is not well supported.  Try `for (int i = 0; argv[1][i]; i++) { fprintf("%d <%c>\n", argv[1][i], argv[1][i]); }` to see what you are really getting as `agrv[1]`.

Comment: You cannot have two files with the same name. The fact that you can create a file alongside another file is a proof that their names are not the same. Note two different names could be *displayed* the same, depending on your environment. Try `LANG=C ls --show-control-chars /path/to/your/dir`.

Comment: The body of your `if` inside the loop is a comparison; it doesn't *do* anything.

Comment: _it creates a file with an identical name in the correct directory, right next to the file that already exists with the same name_: so you mean you have then two files with the exact same names in the same directory? What is the exact file name?

Comment: SO can only work properly if you respond to suggestions and answer questions in a timely manner.

Comment: Edit the post to provide a [mre], including necessary `#include` directives and the two missing `}`. Show the exact command used to execute the program, exact output of running the program and piping the output through `cat -e` (which shows non-printing characters), and the output of `ls | cat -e` in the directory where the program is run.

Answer (score 1):

1. Make certain your input file, that "exist" is not also used someplace else exclusively, like an editor.
2. Form a sibling file.

Example:

```
FILE *outf = fopen("test.txt", "w");
if (outf) {
  fprintf(stderr, "<%s>\n", argv[1]);
  fprintf(outf, "<%s>\n", argv[1]);
  fclose(outf);
}
fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
```

Was that test file located where you expected and with the expected contents?

Post that files contents.